# How to preview a mailer targeted on synchronised data extension ?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, data-synchronization

We've created a mailer (In SFMC) which includes AMP script and is a trigger based mailer. Whenever a new lead is created a mailer should be triggered with recommended items. There is a separate data extension from which lookup is being applied for recommended items.

When I go to Test & Preview section of email, I'm not able to find this particular synchronised data extension on which mailer is being targeted.

1. This synchronised data extension is not contacts. This data extension is child data extension of contact DE.
2. Data integration has been done between sales cloud and marketing cloud.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use Synchronized Data Extensions as a Source for Preview/Test or for Sending from Email Studio. You have to duplicate the synchronized Data Extension into a Regular Data Extension using Automation Studio / Query Activity.

If you need to preview your email, I suggest you create a Test Data Extension that that you can fill with Test Data.

You will find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLG0S.jpg) an image that explains the differences between Synchronized Data Extensions / regular Data Extensions / Salesforce Data Extensions.

Comment: +1 Would you mind posting the link to the page instead of a screen grab?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs This is screenshot from the Marketing Cloud Connect Fast Path Partner Deck by Vladimir Silak. Do you think I am allowed to share Salesforce Partners materials here ?